# Rowfixture in .NET to call a web service with Inputs and validate response object

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

I have the following FitNesse test implemented against .NET. It uses "RowFixture" to return an object which is verified. All this works ok.

**My Question is, how can I pass the "inputs" to the array from the FIT test?
At the monent, this is hard coded internally.**

Here is the FIT test:

```
!|ReturnObjectMultiDimension|
|Id           |Name         |
|1, 2, 3, 4   |a, b, c, d   |
```

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using fit;
using dbfit;


namespace DbFitProject
{
    public class ReturnObjectMultiDimension : RowFixture
    {
        public override Type GetTargetClass()
        {
            return typeof(CustomerObject);
        }

        public override object[] Query()
        {
            CustomerObject[] array = new CustomerObject[1];
            array[0] = new CustomerObject(new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new string[4] {"a","b","c","d" });
            return array;
        }
    }


    public class CustomerObject
    {
        public int[] Id;
        public string[] Name;

        public CustomerObject(int[] Id, string[] Name)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Name = Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to just have a class that creates a customer object list and fitSharp will automatically wrap the list in a fixture to check the results:

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<CustomerObject> MakeListWithIdsNames(int[] ids, string[] names) {
        return new List<CustomerObject> { new CustomerObject(ids, names) };
    }
}

|my class|
|make list with ids|1,2,3,4|names|a,b,c,d|
|id|name|
|1,2,3,4|a,b,c,d|
```

See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/FixtureWrapper.html